# Collapse Margin Against Screen Edge

Tags: html, css, margin

I am attempting to create a responsive layout which collapses the items in a section into multiple lines as needed on small screens. The current behavior works, but it fails to utilize all horizontal space. How can I disable the right margin if an item is the last one on its line?

```css
span {
 white-space: nowrap;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
 margin-right: 10em;
}
```

```html
<h1>Section 1</h1>
<span>Item 1</span>
<span>Item 2</span>
<h1>Section 2</h1>
<span>Item 1</span>
<span>Item 2</span>
<span>Item 3</span>
<span>Item 4</span>
<h1>Section 3</h1>
<span>Item 1</span>
<span>Item 2</span>
<span>Item 3</span>
<span>Item 4</span>
<span>Item 5</span>
<span>Item 6</span>
```

Comment: For this type of layout flexbox would be the perfect candidate. Any reason why you are not using it?

Answer (score 0):

If it possible to change html, you can try this:

```
<section>
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  <span>Item 1</span>
  <span>Item 2</span>
</section>
<section>
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  <span>Item 1</span>
  <span>Item 2</span>
  <span>Item 3</span>
  <span>Item 4</span>
</section>
<section>
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
  <span>Item 1</span>
  <span>Item 2</span>
  <span>Item 3</span>
  <span>Item 4</span>
  <span>Item 5</span>
  <span>Item 6</span>
</section>
```

And use css pseudo selector :last-of-type like that:

```
span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-right: 10em;
}
span:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type

Comment: That disables the margin for the last element in the section, but I am trying to remove the margin for the last element in every line.

Comment: You can try set min-width to span. Can you add screenshot of what you visually try to get?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to wrap each block in a `section` tag with `overflow: hidden`. Then wrap the items in a div that has width equal to 100% + one margin-right , like this : `width: calc(100% + 10em);`.

Here is the full example :

```css
section {
  border: 1px dashed coral;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.items {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: calc(100% + 10em);
}

span {
 white-space: nowrap;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-bottom: 1em;
 margin-right: 10em;
 
 border:1px solid pink;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  
  <div class="items">
    <span>Item 1</span>
    <span>Item 2</span>  
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  
  <div class="items">
    <span>Item 1</span>
    <span>Item 2</span>
    <span>Item 3</span>
    <span>Item 4</span>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
  
  <div class="items">
    <span>Item 1</span>
    <span>Item 2</span>
    <span>Item 3</span>
    <span>Item 4</span>
    <span>Item 5</span>
    <span>Item 6</span>
  </div>
</section>
```